# Avoid unnecessary apply to each

Tags: power-automate

I have an action in a Power Automate flow that returns an array of objects.  In my case, the response will only contain a single item in the array.  I'd like to work with that single item downstream in the flow, but I want to avoid the "Apply To Each" loop that is automatically inserted when I reference any property of the array item.

I know I can use a `Compose` action with the `first()` expression to get the first item in the array.  But doing so hurts usability because the dynamic content window only shows the `Outputs` of the Compose action (i.e., I lose the ease of referencing individual properties of the item in the dynamic content window).

I know I can reference those properties via an expression, but is there a way to get a strongly typed reference to a single array item without incurring an unnecessary Apply to Each?

Answer (score 1):

You can try Parse JSON, this will give you Dynamic content reference once you set it through `first` expression.

[Parse JSON image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mitNU.png)

As an Content input use `first(variables('Array'))` then generate Schema from the sample, the sample must be a single item like this:

```
{
    "ID": "11111-2222-333-4444-555",
    "Column1": "lorem ipsum",
    "Column2": "lorem ipsum 2"
}
```

[Parse JSON reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMcZM.png)